# Join three foreign tables in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, foreign-data-wrapper

I have three foreign tables (`visits, parts, problemdescription`) having a common column named: "`startDateTime`"

I want to join them, so I used the following query:

```
select v."startDateTime", p.znumber, pd.remark FROM visits v
INNER JOIN  parts p
on s."startDateTime"=p."startDateTime" INNER JOIN problemdescription pd
on s."startDateTime"=pd."startDateTime";
```

But I get this error for postgres:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "s"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace s with v, because you haven't table "s".

```
select v."startDateTime", p.znumber, pd.remark FROM visits v
INNER JOIN  parts p
on v."startDateTime"=p."startDateTime" INNER JOIN problemdescription pd
on v."startDateTime"=pd."startDateTime";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and congrats for a well formed answer :)